# what's the distinction between process.stdin and process.stdout vs. http request and response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stdout, stdin

I'm learning Node.js and often enough in the tutorial exercises the assignment is to take some kind of input through process.stdin , modify or filter it and pass it on to process.stdout, meanwhile as a clue there is example code that uses `http.createServer( function(req, res) { req.pipe( function of some sort... res.end()`, and other times it can be something like this `process.stdin.pipe( function "something perhaps involving the through module"...).pipe(process.stdout)` .

Comment: `stdin` takes data from your keyboard. `stdout` displays it on the monitor. `request` and `response` go through the internet. Of course this is a great simplification (you can pipe `stdout` to `stdin` and no devices are involved) but it's more or less how it works. HTTP and standard streams are not related at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the former (processor.stdin/out) is writing a command line program.  The latter (http.createServer) is creating a tiny web-server, where "input" (the page request) and "output" (the resulting pages) will basically be managed by the browser via HTTP. Tutorials which do not demonstrate anything web-specific may use the command line because it is simpler.